# Prove $H(x,y)=\alpha\ln(y)-\beta y+\gamma\ln(x)-\delta x$ is constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given:
$x'=\alpha x-\beta xy,y'=-\gamma y +\delta xy$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta>0$
Prove:
1.For the solution $(x(t),y(t))$ find the value of $y(t)$ where $x(t)$ attains maximum/minimum.
2.(H=consnt) is a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $H(x,y)=\alpha\ln(y)-\beta y+\gamma\ln(x)-\delta x$ is from voltka-lotera

Any hint for the second part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see $\frac{d}{dt}H(x,y)=0$. So
$$ H(x,y)(t)=C. $$
Note that the system has a non-trivial equilibrium point $(\frac{\gamma}{\delta},\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$. Using
$$ \ln x=\ln a+\frac{x-a}{a}-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2a^2}+O((x-a)^3) $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln x&=&\ln\bigg(\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)+\frac{\delta}{\gamma}\bigg(x-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)-\frac{\delta^2}{2\gamma^2}\bigg(x-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)^2+O\bigg(\bigg(x-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)^3\bigg),\\
\ln y&=&\ln\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\bigg(y-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)-\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha^2}\bigg(y-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)^2+O\bigg(\bigg(x-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)^3\bigg).
\end{eqnarray}
So $H(x,y)=C$
$$ -\frac{\beta^2}{2\alpha}\bigg(y-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)^2-\frac{\delta^2}{2\gamma}\bigg(x-\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)^2+\alpha\ln\bigg(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\bigg)+\gamma\ln\bigg(\frac{\gamma}{\delta}\bigg)-\alpha-\gamma+h.o.t=C $$
which is a circle.

Comment: Ok, i'll try this but this shows me only that $H$ is constant but not necessary that $H$ is a closed curve

Comment: @ronkurman, see the update.

Comment: thank you i will look at it now